# variable undefined outside youtube search api function

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube, youtube-api, async-await

I am fetching playlistId from youtube api .

It gives correct output when console output within the youtube search function.

It gives undefined outside youtube search api function.

```
 var playlistId;
async function suggestTrack(genre) {

    youtube.search.list({
      auth: config.youtube.key,
      part: 'id,snippet',
      q: genre
    }, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error: ' + err);
      }
      if (data) {
        console.log(data.items[0].id.playlistId); //getting the id
        playlistId = data.items[0].id.playlistId;

      }
      //process.exit();
    });

    console.log(playlistId);// undefined

const tracks = await youtube_api.getPlaylistTracks(playlistId);
return tracks[Math.floor(tracks.length * Math.random())];

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API call is asynchronous. And you are printing the value of `playlistId` before the response of the api even comes back. You have to wait for the response to come. And since you are using `async` wrap the api call in a `Promise` and use `await`. To promisify the `search.list` method, you have a lot of options, or you can do it yourself, like below

```
function search(key, part, genre) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    youtube.search.list({
      auth: key,
      part: part,
      q: genre
    }, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }
      // use better check for playlistId here
      resolve(data ? data.items[0].id.playlistId : null);
    })
  });
}

// then use it here
async function suggestTrack(genre) {
  const playlistId = await search(config.youtube.key, 'id,snippet', genre);      
  const tracks = await youtube_api.getPlaylistTracks(playlistId);
  return tracks[Math.floor(tracks.length * Math.random())];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`youtube.search.list` is asynchronous. You are trying to access to `playlistId` as it was a part of a synchronous process.

You can wrap the `youtube.search.list` inside a `Promise` to simplify it's use.

---

**OLD WAY**

```
function wrappedSearch() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    youtube.search.list({
      auth: config.youtube.key,
      part: 'id,snippet',
      q: genre
    }, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error: ' + err);

        return reject(err);
      }

      return resolve((data && data.items[0].id.playlistId) || false);
    });
  });
}

async function suggestTrack(genre) {
  const playlistId = await wrappedSearch();

  // Here playlistId is either the playlistId, either false

  console.log(playlistId);

  const tracks = await youtube_api.getPlaylistTracks(playlistId);

  return tracks[Math.floor(tracks.length * Math.random())];
}
```

---

**NEW WAY**

*available in node v8 [doc](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v8.0.0/#improved-support-for-promises)
 [tutorial](http://2ality.com/2017/05/util-promisify.html)*

```
const {
   promisify,
} = require('util');

const youtubeSearchAsync = promisify(youtube.search.list);

async function suggestTrack(genre) {
  const data = await youtubeSearchAsync({
      auth: config.youtube.key,
      part: 'id,snippet',
      q: genre
  });

  const playlistId = (data && data.items[0].id.playlistId) || false;

  console.log(playlistId);

  const tracks = await youtube_api.getPlaylistTracks(playlistId);

  return tracks[Math.floor(tracks.length * Math.random())];
}
```

Comment: @YaShChaudhary i've made a mistake at naming of the var. I just changed it